# I can't receive QR_Code to scan on email

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, email, qr-code

I'm working on a flutter app, where the user will receive a QR code in his email to scan it in order to get access.

I implement node js server with the code below:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Dummy QR code data (you should generate or fetch actual QR code data)
const dummyQRCodeData = {
  qrCodeUrl: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G_XpQ2AOXQvHyEsdttyhY_Y3raqie-LI/view?usp=sharing',
};

// Endpoint to send QR code to an email
app.post('/api/send-qrcode', (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;

  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email is required' });
  }

  // Here you can send the QR code data to the provided email
  // In this example, we'll just send back the dummy QR code data
  res.json({ success: true, qrCodeData: dummyQRCodeData });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The qrcode controller. dart file

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class QRCodeController {
  Future<String> getQRCode(String email) async {
    String urlString = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/qrCode?email=$email';
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlString));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // La requête a réussi, vous pouvez traiter la réponse ici
      String responseBody = response.body;
      return responseBody;
    } else {
      // La requête a échoué avec un code de statut autre que 200
      print('Échec de la requête : ${response.statusCode}');
      return "null";
    }
  }
}
```

The layoutLogin.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/config/constants/color_theme.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/controllers/qrCodeController.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/connexion/components/button.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/connexion/components/textInput.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/connexion/views/indexQR.dart';
//import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/produits/views/indexProductList.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/utils/provider.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class LayoutLogin extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const LayoutLogin({
    super.key,
    required this.formKey,
  });

  final formKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final mailController = TextEditingController();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Email",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .displayMedium
                    ?.copyWith(color: AppColor.primary80, fontSize: 25),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextInput(
                      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
                      label: "Veuillez renseigner votre email",
                      placeholder: "Entre ton email",
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Veuillez saisir votre adresse e-mail';
                        }
                        final emailRegex =
                            RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$');
                        if (!emailRegex.hasMatch(value)) {
                          return 'Veuillez saisir une adresse e-mail valide';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      controller: mailController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              DefaultButton(
                color: AppColor.primary80,
                text: "Envoyer",
                /*
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const IndexProductList(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                */
                onPressed: () {
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const IndexQR(
                            qrCodeUrl: null,
                          ));
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    QRCodeController qrCodeController = QRCodeController();
                    String email = ref.watch(inputValueProvider);
                    email = email.replaceAll('@', '%40');
                    qrCodeController.getQRCode(email).then((qrCodeData) {
                      if (qrCodeData != "") {
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const IndexQR(
                                      qrCodeUrl: null,
                                    )),
                          );
                        });
                      } else {
                        // La requête a échoué
                        print('La requête a échoué.');
                      }
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that the user couldn't receive the QR Code in the email. Thanks for help